# Javascript: How to convert AJAX returned string representation of an array to an array

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays

I must convert a string representation of an array of objects returned from AJAX to an array of objects in JavaScript.

```
ajaxret = "[{a:'a', b:'b', c: 1},{a:'aa', b:'ab', c: 2},{a:'aaa', b:'bbb', c: 3}]"

strResult = [{a:'a', b:'b', c: 1},{a:'aa', b:'ab', c: 2},{a:'aaa', b:'bbb', c: 3}]
```

Comment: If it's valid JSON (which your string is *not*), you can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).  How are you creating `ajaxret`?  Why is it returning an invalid JSON string?  If you can fix `ajaxret`, then `JSON.parse()` will work great :)

Comment: What's missing to make it a valid JSON string?

Comment: The keys are not quoted.  Both the keys and (string) values need to be quoted in double quotes.  How are you creating this JSON?

Comment: VB.Net is used to create a colModel used to load a jqGrid grid. It is originally converted to a simple js array in the Page_Load event using  stringBuilder.AppendFormat. However when the same string is requested using Ajax it needs to be loaded into the page using Javascript. In any case, it sounds like there is no easy way to do it. I'll have to try to quote the keys to see if the original page Append.Format will convert it.

Comment: Check to see if there's a *native* JSON function.  *Don't* build the JSON manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you serialize your objects into strings, you should produce valid JSON, using

```
var string = JSON.stringify(object);
```

To parse to an object again, then you can use

```
var object = JSON.parse(string);
```

In your case, since you have invalid JSON, the simple way is

```
var object = eval(string);
```

**Warning!!!**

- `eval` is evil
- Use it only if the source is **completely** trusted
- A malicious source could execute arbitrary code. So bad!
- `JSON.parse` is probably faster

Comment: Eval(ajaxRet) worked. How dangerous is it? ajaxRet is completely controlled by the code that creates it based on existing table data which is filled by user input which is added using OleDbCommand using parameters.

Comment: @RobGMiller If `ajaxRet` contains user input, it should be ok to `eval` it in that user's machine, but not in others' one. Anyway, better use JSON.